# What do telegraph posts do?

Tags: battlefield-1

In Rush if you interact with a telegraph post as a defender you are allegedly giving the artillery coordinates of the attackers.

But what does that mean in-game?

Comment: I think they may be bugged because they seem to do a whole lot of nothing.

Comment: @Rapitor yeah, that's why I'm asking, I don't see any immediate effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of release version this *is* working. Telegraphs call in artillery strike on the currently spotted enemies.

This is particularly effective as a way to destroy camping tanks.